# Is the ChildBrowser plugin for Android supposed to run on the emulator?

Tags: android, plugins, android-emulator, cordova

Is the ChildBrowser plugin for Android supposed to work on the emulator? cuz I think I have everything setup as [explained here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/ChildBrowser/README.md) but I dont have a real device to test it out. When running the app it doesnt trigger it after clicking the button. Ive put some console stuff there and is in fact reaching that point to run the script: window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage(url, true););

The iPhone version of the plugin runs beautifully.

btw, Im using the latest version of both phonegap: 0.9.4 and the ChildBrowser plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind :) somehow eclipse -as lazy as can be- needs to be aware of the ChildBrowser.java existence even though it's already there, stored at the proper place within the project!

Answer (score 0):

Right. Eclipse drives the .apk file build so it needs to know about all of the files to include in the build.